# Spark Job RPC Issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

My spark job succeeds but it takes longer time than usual.

Getting the following message repeatedly in the driver node when the job gets accepted as well as when it's running -

```
20/05/01 01:17:05 INFO resource.u: Set a new configuration for the first time.
20/05/01 01:17:06 INFO reflect.d: Method not implemented in this version of Hadoop: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getGlobalStorageStatistics
20/05/01 01:17:06 INFO reflect.d: Method not implemented in this version of Hadoop: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics.getBytesReadLocalHost
20/05/01 01:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
20/05/01 01:17:06 INFO resource.l: Scheduling statistics report every 2000 millisecs
20/05/01 01:17:06 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
20/05/01 01:17:08 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
20/05/01 01:17:10 INFO zookeeper.ZKDataRetrieval: Process path: null. Event state: SyncConnected. Event type: None
20/05/01 01:17:10 INFO zookeeper.ZKDataRetrieval: Getting serviceData for master node of resourcemanager
20/05/01 01:17:10 INFO zookeeper.ZKDataRetrieval: Process path: null. Event state: SaslAuthenticated. Event type: None
20/05/01 01:17:10 INFO rpc.b: Could not get any http protocol, using HTTP and will try to get protocol again
```

Comment: what is the complete stack trace or error in detail. no proper formatting very less information given

Comment: Hey @user2597100, Did you manage to identify the source of the error?